# Notify me when a bounty is placed on one of my questions

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications

Placing a bounty on a question changes its *last activity* timestamp and bumps it to the front page, the same as posting a new answer or editing the question or one of its answers.

It would be nice to be notified when someone else is assigning a bounty on one of your own questions - it might be just a notification in the brand new notification tab of the  StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ instead of a full inbox message.

Comment: Consider yourself notified. :P

Comment: @Shokhet lol, this works well! ;-)

Comment: Voting not to close as a duplicate. This question asks to notify for questions you've asked; the other for questions you've asked **or answered**. IMO these are related but slightly different feature-requests.

Comment: @S.L.Barth not different enough to justify both being open IMO, used self hammer to close.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to propose an addendum: With the notification, also display a list of your questions with bounties (active or inactive) in a tab along side the other bounty tabs on your user profile.

With this in place, I'd expect to see something like:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Active | Offered | Earned | My Questions |
--------------------------------------------
```