# Give a commision to the asker on bounties other people place

Tags: discussion, bounties

Placing a bounty on someone else's question tells the asker "I really want to see this answered". But aside from a single upvote (presumably) and extra traffic (which may or may not result in more votes), the asker is never really rewarded for making a question that someone feels is good enough to spend rep on.

This concept is to give the asker a more concrete bonus when someone else puts a bounty on one of their questions. Here are a few ideas:

- `+5` Basically a second upvote, assuming that you'll have upvoted any question you've bountied.
- `+10` Setting a bounty is a stronger action than a simple upvote.
- `+5%` Same as the first idea, but providing bigger bonuses if the offered bounty is larger. Presumably only the best questions get the biggest bounties, why not reward them?
- `+10%` If you're wiling to spend 500 rep on someone else's question, perhaps they deserve an extra 50 rep for writing such a question.

This commision would not be subtracted from the bounty amount; it would be generated from nowhere just like upvotes.

As a nice side effect, the bonus would notify users that a question of theirs has been bountied by someone else, which [I don't think currently occurs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137853/notify-me-when-a-bounty-is-placed-on-one-of-my-questions).

<sub>This is a discussion, not a feature request. I don't know if we need this or want this, but it's an interesting idea so I put it out there.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

I think the additional traffic and possible additional upvotes should be enough.

Introducing bounty commissions

- adds another complicated set of rules to the reputation system which is already complicated enough
- adds another layer of issues that people will complain about ("A bounty was withdrawn and I lost my commission!" "My question was deleted after a bounty and I lost my commission. I think I should get to keep the bounty because...")
- opens massive gaming possibilities (especially if rep is created from nowhere)
- will often be unjustified. There are very basic highly upvoted questions (especially older ones) that are upvoted just because they ask the question, not because they are especially high quality. (Stuff like "how to do xyz with jQuery?") Those will attract bounties, but they don't really deserve a reward beyond what they already got.

If a question is really good, it will receive further upvotes from being featured.

Comment: +1 especially for pointing out the potential for gaming the system.

Comment: A 200 rep bounty I placed on someone's question gave him an additional 27 or so upvotes that he probably wouldn't have gotten otherwise. That's a net rep of 135 and badges. That was plenty of a commission for something that was essentially free to him. If anything, the person who offered the bounty on with a successful turnout should get some of that back (not that I'm asking for that).

Answer (score 4):

I will disagree based on this erroneous assumption:

> aside from a single upvote (presumably) and extra traffic (which may or may not result in more votes), the asker is never really rewarded for making a question that someone feels is good enough to spend rep on.

The asker **gets an answer awesome enough to be worthy of a bounty** (or at least gets more effort put in by experts towards providing a quality answer to their question. Considering the need for an answer is the *reason they asked the question in the first place*, I'd say that's a pretty good reward.

[Pekka's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143631/167443) is pretty good reasoning as well.

Comment: If the question that is bountied by other is not yet answered, you get free advertisement. YOU should pay for it:) If we start to think of this further..